# Simple javascript if statement but can't find where is wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

Simple if but can't find where is problem. Why my form return alert if values are correct?

```
if ( (($("#tip1").val()) > (value + tolerance)) || 
     (($("#tip1").val()) < (value + tolerance)) || 
     (($("#tip2").val()) < (value + tolerance)) || 
     (($("#tip2").val() ) > (value + tolerance))
   ){
       alert('STOP');
}
```

If my values are correct or not correct return alert any time;

Comment: thats a super simple if statement alright

Comment: Well, at least whenever you use < you should use `value - tolerance` with a minus, and also check that `$("#tip")` is correct.

Comment: did you check your condition. I think whatever value you give it satisfies the condition because you are using || operator which returns true if one of the condition is true

Comment: What are the values of `$("#tip1").val()`, `$("#tip2").val()`, `value`, and `tolerance`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder He just confirmed it in a comment in Girish's answer.

Comment: So i need convert so Float first?

Comment: @Barmar real type data exmp 521.4

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this? Are you trying to test whether any of the fields are outside `value +/- tolerance`?

Comment: Should the last one be `$("#tip")` or `$("#tip2")`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Updated answer** based on comments and updated question:

Based on the names "value" and "tolerance" and your comments below, I think the problem is in you need `value - tolerance` when doing the `<` checks. E.g.:

```
var tip1Value = $("#tip1").val();
var tip2Value = $("#tip2").val();
if ( tip1Value > (value + tolerance) || 
     tip1Value < (value - tolerance) ||  // <== - not +
     tip2Value < (value - tolerance) ||  // <== - not +
     tip2Value > (value + tolerance)
   ){
       alert('STOP');
}
```

So for instance, suppose `value` is `450` and `tolerance` is `15`, and we're testing (`test`) the value `440`:

```
// 440 should be fine if we want 450 -+ 15
test = 440;

// Your original test:
console.log(440 < (450 + 15)); // true => fails, we get the alert -- 440 < 465

// Corrected test:
console.log(440 < (450 - 15)); // false, the value is okay
```

---

I would also put the tests for tip1 and tip2 in the same order, to avoid confusion, and probably give myself a meaningful name for `value + tolerance` and `value - tolerance`:

```
var tip1Value = $("#tip1").val();
var tip2Value = $("#tip2").val();
var maxValue = value + tolerance;
var minValue = value - tolerance;
if ( tip1Value > maxValue || 
     tip1Value < minValue ||
     tip2Value > maxValue ||
     tip2Value < minValue
   ){
       alert('STOP');
}
```

---

**Original answer**:

Your statement says:

If #tip1's value is `> (value + tolerance)`

**OR**

#tip1's value is `< (value + tolerance)`

**OR**

#tip2's value is `> (value + tolerance)`

**OR**

#tip's value is `> (value + tolerance)`

..then do the alert.

Only **one** of them has to be true to show the alert. So if you're seeing the alert, it means one of those four conditions is true. Only you can find out which one.

Those first two conditions, of course, can be combined into

```
(($("#tip1").val()) != (value + tolerance))
```

---

Speculations on what the error is:

- You didn't mean to use the value from three different elements (`#tip1`, `#tip2`, `#tip`), e.g., perhaps at least one of those is a typo (the last is pretty suspicious).
- If both `value` and `tolerance` are *strings* (for instance, if you got them from `.val()` in code you haven't shown), then `value + tolerance` is doing string concatenation, not addition. E.g., `"1" + "2"` is `"12"`. But for that to be happening, *both* have to be strings rather than numbers (`1 + "2"` is `3`, and `"1" + 2` is also `3`).
- Based on the names "value" and "tolerance", when doing the `<` comparisons, you may have meant to use `(value - tolerance)`. E.g., if the goal is to see if `12` is within `3` (tolerance) of `14`, you'd want `tipvalue < (value - tolerance)`.

Comment: Yes but if i enter values exmp 500 and 500 and my value = 500 and tolerance = 15 then should be ok

Comment: I need alert if any one condition is true

Comment: if my i enter 500 but my value= 450 then 500 < (450 + 15 ) and 500 > (450 - 15)

Comment: @user3747585: Yes, it should. And barring information you haven't shown, it will be.

Comment: @user3747585: *"if my i enter 500 but my value= 450 then 500 < (450 + 15 ) and 500 > (450 - 15)"* You have that backward. The tests should be `500 > (450 + 15 )` and `500 < (450 - 15)`.

Comment: Crowder it is range of values

Comment: @user3747585: I understand that. You're testing whether the input is within 15 (tolerance) of 450. Your tests using `<` should use `value - tolerance`. See the updated answer above based on your comments and corrected question (you might need to hit refresh).

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that, `$("#tip1").val()` will return string type. . So you should convert that sting to number by either use `parseInt` or `parseFloat` .

```
var tip1Value = parseFloat($("#tip1").val());
var tipValue = parseFloat($("#tip").val());
var tip2Value = parseFloat($("#tip2").val());;
if (tip1Value > (value + tolerance) || tip1Value < (value + tolerance)) || tip2Value < (value + tolerance)) || tipValue > (value + tolerance)) {
    alert('STOP');
}
```

Comment: this is not "1" > 2 = false

Comment: *"$("#tip1").val() will return string type. So you can't use < operator with that."* Yes you can. If either argument is a number, the other is coerced to a number.

Comment: The OP's code is using the value from multiple different elements (`#tip1`, `#tip2`, `#tip`); your code is only using the value from `#tip1`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Sorry. My bad, I edited the if condition.